# Importance of "standalone" class

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

Assume that i have a document, in which i should produce lots of plots from csv files with "tikz" package. To plot them externally, it is suggested to use the standalone class and place each figure in a separate tex file.

Why shouldn't/can't we easily produce a png or pdf in the separated file, and then include the produced pdf/png using \includegraphics...? what is the point of using \includestandalone...?

The question came to my mind when I encountered the following problem when i used the standalone class:
I have:

```
./
├── figures/
│   ├── /csv/sub.csv
│   └── sub.tex
├── main.tex
```

when i compile sub.tex using "\addplot{csv/sub.csv}" , it produces the pdf file correctly. But when i call \includestandalone{figures\sub} in the main.tex, i get the following error:
"! Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file..."

If it was supposed to produce the figure externally, why does the main file need to access the csv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use `\includestandalone`, if you prefer `\includegraphics` directly on the PDF, just do that.

The behaviour of `\includestandalone` depends on the value of the `mode` key, see the `standalone` manual. The default is to read the source file directly (just like `\input`) but you can for example tell it to use the existing image/PDF (`mode=image`), or to always generate the image/PDF and then include that (`mode=build`), or only build if the source is newer than the image/PDF (`mode=buildnew`).